# Show Joomla module only in specific articles?

Tags: templates, module, joomla, joomla-article

Is it possible to show modules in Joomla only in a specific article (not per menu item), but in standard module position?

For example somehow get the current article id in a template and insert the modules with according id suffix in the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you not to hardcode things like this in the template. My question is, why don't you want to use a menu item? You can create a hidden menu item for that article and use it, then assign the module to that menu item.
If you still want to do it without using a menu item, a possible workaround would be to use something like "mod_php" (some module that allows you to use php code) and do something more or less like this:

1. Create the module and assign it to a position that is not used anywhere (you can type whatever you want in the module position)
2. In your php module, put this code:

   ```
   $option = JRequest::getVar( 'option', '' );

   $view = JRequest::getVar( 'view', '' );

   $id = JRequest::getInt( 'id', 0 );

   if ( $option == "com_content" && $view == "article" && $id == YOUR_ARTICLE_ID ) {    

       $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('your_module_type', 'module_title');

       if ( ! empty( $module ) ) {
           $attribs = array( 'style' => 'xhtml' );
           echo JModuleHelper::renderModule( $module, $attribs ); 
       }
    }
   ```

I'm sorry if the code snippet is not showing properly, but I hope you can read it ok. Just one thing, when you fill in the part saying 'your_module_type', don't include the "mod_" part of the name. For example, if you want to output a module of type "mod_article_list", you should write "article_list" in "your_module_type".

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer..Looks promising..
Actually I will try the solution with menu items..I did not know that when there is the hidden menu item solution:) 
As I figured out, the article-menuitem reference works both sides..Thats cool. Going to try that right now!

Comment: Hey so I created really simple module with the code you posted and YES its working!thank you..

Comment: Actually I think the second and chosen solution is much cleaner, isnt it?

Comment: Nope, I think it's much better the hidden menu item solution. Think for a moment if you don't wanted to print a single module with the article, but 10 different modules.. It would be a matter of just assigning these modules to a menu item, but with the second solution you would have to write 10 php modules.. Anyway, I'm glad it helped

Comment: @alghimo in menu assignment setting I must set it to show in all pages? module title is just the name I write in title field?